# why antd switch rendering is not working?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, switch-statement, antd

I try to make typescript react setting
and then just install antd
 `$ yarn add antd`
and fix app.tsx like this

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Switch } from "antd";

function App() {
  function onChange(checked: any) {
    console.log(`switch to ${checked}`);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but i can't see right switch
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmGjJ.png

i want to look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKVWW.png

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "antd": "^4.18.8",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

How to solve this rendering problem?

Comment: `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';`

Comment: wow... why auto adding css in my app? 
i wondering am i install `yarn antd` that is auto add css together?